# Command Prompt Python

Tags: python, terminal, progress-bar, command-prompt

What is the benefit of running code through the command prompt/terminal vs an ide?

I've noticed recently when using the progressbar module of python that the progress text is updated on the same line in the command prompt window while the ide prints each text on the next line. Why are these different? Are they not running though the same interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE adds an extra layer of software between the program and the python interpreter.

What you are seeing is probably that the IDE's output window is not a complete terminal emulator, and doesn't understand or ignores the commands that the progressbar module uses. to keep the output on the same line.

Have a look at [ipython](http://ipython.org/). It is a *very* nice environment for testing and running python code.

Answer (score 1):

Each IDE is infact interacting via the command line  and redirecting streams into it's implementation of showing those outputs, Each IDE has it's own way of doing this, command prompt is more powerful if you are expeirienced and easy to try one off scripts, try ipython which is great for beginners and learners alike for fast access to the programming environment and trying out module.